# JSP и сервлет реализация

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, сервлеты

Как можно реализовать с помощью JSP и сервлета. Есть переменные на JSP файле, и к ней кнопки, по которым переменные изменяются. То есть на одну кнопку я могу нажать 10 раз, и хотелось видеть результат изменений в этой переменной.

В инете не нашел. Есть примеры, где передаешь данные, от одного jsp-файла на сервер в другой jsp-файл. А именно работа с одним jsp не нашел((

Вот jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Game" method = "get"> 
<h1>Играем в 21(очко).</h1>
У сервера карт: ${serverKart}<br><br><br>
В колоде карт: ${kolodaKart}<br><br><br>

Ваши карты: ${kart}<br>
Очков: ${ozkov} <br>
 ${Ozibka} <br>

<input type="submit" value="Взять карту" name="button1" > <input type="submit" value="Пропустить ход" name="button2"> <input type="submit" value="Рестарт" name="button3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

и сервлет

```
    package ru.unlimit;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import ru.model.CardIgra;


    @WebServlet("/Game")
    public class Game extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        CardIgra cardIgra;

        public Game() {
            super();
            cardIgra = new CardIgra();

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

             /* if (request.getParameter("button1") != null) {
                  String coobzenie = "";
                  if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard().size() == 5)
                      request.setAttribute("Ozibka", "Пропустите ход, у вас максимум карт");
                  else {
                  cardIgra.bratKartyPlayer();

                        if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getOzki() == 21)
                            request.setAttribute("Ozibka", "Вы выиграли");
                        else if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getOzki() > 21)
                            request.setAttribute("Ozibka", "Вы проиграли");

                  }



                } else if (request.getParameter("button2") != null) {
                   // myClass.method2();
                } else if (request.getParameter("button3") != null) {
                   cardIgra.startPlayer();

                request.setAttribute("serverKart", cardIgra.getPlayerServer().getArrayCard().size());
                request.setAttribute("kolodaKart", cardIgra.getCardkoloda().size());
                request.setAttribute("kart", cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard().size());
                request.setAttribute("ozkov", cardIgra.getPlayer().getOzki());

                */
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
                request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
                request.setAttribute("Ozibka", 3);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("Game.jsp").forward(request, response); 
        }
        }
```

Comment: Просто подставьте вместо второго сервлета первый. Получится один.

Comment: вы хотите, что бы значение менялось без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman, да

Comment: @Sergey не совсем вас понял

Comment: Приведите свой код, а там посмотрим. Не понятно точно чего Вы хотите.

Comment: @Sergey выложил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменяться должна какая переменная? cardIgra? Другой вроде нет.
Что jsp, что servlet, оба живут только в течении обработки текущего запроса.
Поэтому Ваша cardIgra пропадает каждый раз по завершении этой обработки.

Вам нужно создать сессию и поместить переменную в сессию. Тогда изменения переменной, сделанные в прошлом запросе, будут видны в следующем.

Самый простой способ, который знаю, это использование CDI (внедрение зависимостей)

К классу CardIgra добавьте аннотацию `@SessionScoped`. Должно получиться так

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
public class CardIgra implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Класс, который размещается в сессии, должен быть Serializable.
(Есть ещё один SessionScoped, тоже должен работать, но с ним я дела не имею.  SessionScoped для CDI находится в javax.enterprise.context. Поэтому добавил import)

Теперь сервер знает что класс CardIgra можно внедрять, что экземпляр этого класса должен быть в сессии. И к нашей радости при внедрении сервер сам создаст сессию, если надо.

Осталось только внедрить CardIgr-у. Для этого изменим сервлет таким образом

```
@WebServlet("/Game")
public class Game extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject CardIgra cardIgra;

    public Game() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    ...
}
```

`@Inject` заставит внедрить поле cardIgra при создании сервлета. Таким нехитрым образом сервлет получит ссылку на переменную из сессии. Из конструктора убрано создание переменной. Сервер сделает всё сам.

Можно ещё дать имя CardIgr-е

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CardIgra implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Тогда к ней можно будет обратиться по имени (по умолчанию имя класса с маленькой буквы) в jsp

```
${cardIgra.playerServer.arrayCard.size()}
${cardIgra.player.ozki}
```

Возможно Вам понадобится такой файл в WEB-INF/beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

У меня он где-то есть, где-то нет. Он говорит о том, что бы сервер искал CDI- бины по аннотациям.

Comment: как я понял вы используете сервер GlassFish

Comment: через Tomcat это можно реализовать?

Comment: CDI входит в WEB-профиль набора спецификаций java ee, поэтому должен быть и в tomcat-е.

Comment: добавил все зависимости. У вас указано что сервер сам создаст переменную класса CardIgra.  И у меня возникает ошибка  при вызове if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard().size() == 5) что ссылается на нулевой объект

Comment: Проверьте что нулевой объект именно cardIgra, а не далее по цепочке. `cardIgra.getPlayer()`, `cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard()`

Comment: дело в том что переменная cardIgra нулевой объект

Comment: Поправил ответ. В самом конце. Попробуйте сделать такой файл. Какой версии tomcat? Есть мнение, что tomcat 7 не поддерживает CDI, тогда это решение не для Вас к сожалению.

Comment: сейчас посмотрю. Версия 8.5

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает

Comment: @ Sergey, можно у переменной cardIgra вызвать конструктор один раз?

Comment: Если класс Game планируется использовать ещё каким-то образом и Вы хотите всегда иметь в нём cardIgr-у, то можете вызывать конструктор СardIgra в конструкторе Game(), Ничего зазорного в этом нет. Но учтите, что @Inject в сервлете перепишет cardIgr-у из конструктора cardIgr-ой из сессии.